# Norm of vector greater than norm of its orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v=v_p+v_o$ be the splitting of a vector along a given vector $w$. Show that:

$||v|| \ge ||v_p||$ and $||v|| \ge ||v_o||$.

I know that $v_p= \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{||w||^2} w$ and $v_o= v- \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{||w||^2} w$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Pythagoras? ${}$

Comment: What is that supposed to mean after the edit? It does not resemble the original question, and nothing in the edited version is comprehensible.

Comment: Please, don't change the content of your question. You can edit it for clarification and/or overall improvement, but not to change its core content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to orthogonality, $\langle v_o,v_p \rangle = 0$, and we get 
\begin{align}
\Vert v \Vert^2 &= \langle v,v \rangle = \langle v_o+v_p,v_o+v_p \rangle\\
&= \langle v_o,v_o \rangle + \langle v_o,v_p \rangle + \langle v_p,v_o \rangle + \langle v_p,v_p \rangle\\
&= \Vert v_o \Vert^2 + \Vert v_p \Vert^2,
\end{align}
so
$$ \Vert v \Vert^2 = \Vert v_o \Vert^2 + \Vert v_p \Vert^2 \geq \Vert v_o \Vert^2 , $$
and
$$ \Vert v \Vert^2 = \Vert v_o \Vert^2 + \Vert v_p \Vert^2 \geq \Vert v_p \Vert^2. $$

Comment: that's a nice derivation!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that $|v|$,$|v_0|$ and $|v_p|$ form a right triangle.

Comment: Geometric intuition is the best hint one can possibly get!

Comment: @Sobi I agree it's a foundamental guide, but the algebrical derivation is also necessary to confirm the intuition!